# SpriteKit weird behaviour of SKSpriteNode property

Tags: swift, floating-point, sprite-kit, cgpoint

I'm moving my first steps into SpriteKt and found this apparently weird behaviour of the `SkSpriteNode.position` property: it should be a `CGPoint`, but when assigned and read back, it behaves differently of any other CGPoint.

In the code that follows I have tested some randomly chosen points. Some of them can be assigned to the `SkSpriteNode.position` property and read back again and everything seems to work fine.

Some other, when assigned, are rounded to some other (close) value.
It could be a floating-point value representation round off issue, but than comes the super weird thing: the exact same `CGPoint`, when assigned to another `CGPoint` (not to the `position` property, which, by the way, claims to be a `CGPoint`) the round off doesn't appear 
Does anybody knows what's going on?

```
check(position: CGPoint.zero)
check(position: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1))
check(position: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 700))
check(position: CGPoint(x: -500, y: 200))
check(position: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5))
check(position: CGPoint(x: 1.12, y: 1.14))
check(position: CGPoint(x: 1.12, y: 1.1415161718))

func check(position: CGPoint) {
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: .cyan, size: CGSize(width: 32, height: 32))
    let point = position
    sprite.position = position
    print("position = \(position)")
    print("point = \(point)")
    print("sprite = \(sprite.position)")
    if sprite.position == position {
        print("✅ they match")
    } else {
        print("❌ they don't match")
    }
    assert(position == point, "assign \(position) to point result in \(point)")
}
```

On my system (Xcode Version 12.5 (12E262)) output is:

```
position = (0.0, 0.0)
point = (0.0, 0.0)
sprite = (0.0, 0.0)
✅ they match
position = (1.0, 1.0)
point = (1.0, 1.0)
sprite = (1.0, 1.0)
✅ they match
position = (100.0, 700.0)
point = (100.0, 700.0)
sprite = (100.0, 700.0)
✅ they match
position = (-500.0, 200.0)
point = (-500.0, 200.0)
sprite = (-500.0, 200.0)
✅ they match
position = (0.5, 0.5)
point = (0.5, 0.5)
sprite = (0.5, 0.5)
✅ they match
position = (1.12, 1.14)
point = (1.12, 1.14)
sprite = (1.1200000047683716, 1.1399999856948853)
❌ they don't match
position = (1.12, 1.1415161718)
point = (1.12, 1.1415161718)
sprite = (1.1200000047683716, 1.1415162086486816)
❌ they don't match
```

Comment: The 1.12 and 1.14 is the classic floating point issue and the inaccuracies which go with it. My guess with your "point" variable would be that it is just storing a reference to the memory address of the CGPoint position, and not actually copying or doing anything with it. Whereas sprite.position would not be referencing the CGPoint position, but creating/copying its own version of the CGPoint position into a new section of memory. This is where the floating point issue comes in. That is my best guess anyway.

Comment: thank you @JohnL for your reply! As far as I know, CGPoint should be a struct and, unless the compiler does some crazy stuff, when you assign a value type to another, in theory the contents are copied. Maybe I'm wrong, but the Swift compiler optimizes this with a copy-on-change strategy. This should hold true both for the `point` variable and for the `position` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally the sprite is using 32-bit single-precision floats.  The normal CGPoint is 64-bit double-precision.  Assigning sprite.position is rounding 64-bit to 32-bit, and then for the printing and comparison it's going back from 32-bit to 64-bit.  Your initial examples all happen to be numbers that are exactly representable in both 32- and 64-bits, so no loss of precision is happening there.

Comment: Thank you @bg2b for your reply!
May I ask how I could ever known that SpriteKit internally uses 32-bit floats? It doesn't seem to have much sense nowadays when all CPU are 64 bit ‍♂️

Comment: Sprites are generally going to be dealt with on the GPU, which is typically optimized for 32-bit. In any case you can tell for this example since the trip through `position` is giving the same result as IEEE double to float to double.

Comment: Thank you @bg2b! I have too much to learn